# Do iterators of OpenCV Mat.row()'s not work with stdlib algortihms?

Tags: c++, opencv, iterator, std

While implementing some image processing algorithms i came across a strange behaviour of OpenCV. The goal is to use Mat.row(i) and OpenCV iterators (Mat.begin() / Mat.end()) of this row to apply algorithms of the C++ standard library (like std::transform, std::accumulate, etc.) to the underlying data.

```
#include <numeric>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 4;
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;

    cv::Mat_<float> mat(rows,cols);
    iota(mat.begin(),mat.end(),0);

    // Element access works (result is always 5)
    cout << mat(x,y) << endl;
    cout << *(mat.begin()+x*mat.cols+y) << endl;
    cout << *(mat.row(x).begin()+y) << endl;

    // Range is correct for the Mat (result is 12 = rows * cols) ...
    cout << mat.end() - mat.begin() << endl;     
    cout << mat.begin()+x*mat.cols - mat.begin()+(x+1)*mat.cols << endl;

    // ... but incorrect for the row (9223372036854775807)
    cout << mat.row(x).end() - mat.row(x).begin() << endl;

    // So this works (result is 22 = 4+5+6+7 = sum of row 1) ...
    cout << accumulate(mat.begin()+x*mat.cols,mat.begin()+(x+1)*mat.cols,static_cast<float>(0)) << endl;

    // ... but this does not.
    cout << accumulate(mat.row(x).begin(),mat.row(x).end(),static_cast<float>(0)) << endl;

}
```

It looks that the Iterators for the row selection cannot execute the "-" operation, while the iterators for the entire Mat can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *Mat::begin* and *Mat::end* but these functions must be applied to the same `Mat` object. In this line

```
cout << mat.row(x).end() - mat.row(x).begin() << endl;
```

the first call of `mat.row(x)` created new `Mat` object, and the second call of `mat.row(x)` created another new `Mat` object. You cannot substract result of *end()* and *begin()* because they refer to different objects.
You can write

```
cv::Mat_<float> rowMat = mat.row(x);
cout << rowMat.end() - rowMat.begin() << endl; // works
```

and

```
cout << accumulate(rowMat.begin(),rowMat.end(),static_cast<float>(0)) << endl;
```

works also.